# Issue With An Unserialized Array display in A Loop

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

Referring to my question:
[Displaying Serialized Array PHP MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76685765/displaying-serialized-array-php-mysql?noredirect=1#comment135242308_76685765)

I have a serialized array stored in MYSQL. I am unserializing and then displaying in table  using below code. The code works fine but values are merged in each row. Suppose, ist row had value 3 and second row had value 4 then ist row display 3, which is fine but second row shows 3,4 and similarly, ist row values are merged with other row values.
Please assist.

Thanks

**Code:**

```
$abc='';
foreach($result as $row)
  {
  $fine_types = unserialize($row['fine_type']);
  echo "<td>";
    foreach ($fine_types as $fine_type) {
            $abc .="<div dir='rtl' lang='ar' class='fntype'> ".$fine_type.'</div>';
        //$r=implode(',')
    }
    echo "</td>";
  

 `$output .= '
    <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right;">' . $abc . '</td></tr>';
}
echo $output;`
```

**Example of A Generated serialized String**

a:3:{i:0;s:177:"66   -   عدم تخزين وحفظ المواد الغذائية الجافة والمبردة والمجمدة في درجة مناسبة حرارة مناسبة لكل نوع";i:1;s:76:"13   -   عدم وجود لوحة إعلانية بالاسم التجاري";i:2;s:63:"9   -   إضافة فرع أو مستودع بدون ترخيص";}

**Above String in Unserialized Format**

66 - عدم تخزين وحفظ المواد الغذائية الجافة والمبردة والمجمدة في درجة مناسبة حرارة مناسبة لكل نوع,

13 - عدم وجود لوحة إعلانية بالاسم التجاري,

9 - إضافة فرع أو مستودع بدون ترخيص

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly now, the problem is that it keeps adding the output of previous `$row` contents into your output when it processes subsequent rows, resulting in a problem like we see in this live demo: https://3v4l.org/eXXRX.

If so, that is because `$abc` is not reset each time the outer `foreach` is executed. You can easily fix that by moving `$abc='';` inside that loop:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
  $abc='';
  $fine_types = unserialize($row['fine_type']);
  
  echo "<td>";
  foreach ($fine_types as $fine_type) {
    $abc .="<div dir='rtl' lang='ar' class='fntype'> ".$fine_type.'</div>';
  }
  echo "</td>";

  $output .= '
    <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right;">' . $abc . '</td></tr>';
}
echo $output;
```

Demo with correction: https://3v4l.org/vCQ5V